# Random walk plotting in python

Tags: python

I have been working through the book "A student's guide to Python for Physical Modeling" by Jesse M. Kinder & Philip Nelson and there is an exercise where I'm instructed to build a Brownian motion simulator/ random walk simulator and plot it. I don't know why my code is not working and I was hoping I could get some help from you:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random as rng

def Brownian_motion(steps):
    """
    this is a random walk function
    define the number of steps to be taken as a integer value
    """
    #these are the random numbers
    steps_x = rng(steps)
    steps_y = rng(steps)

    #Here I change the random numbers to 1 or -1
    pace_x = (steps_x < 0.5)
    for i in pace_x:
        if i == False:
            pace_x[i] = -1
        else:
            pace_x[i] = 1
        return pace_x

    pace_y = (steps_y < 0.5)
    for i in pace_y:
        if i == False:
            pace_y[i] = -1
        else:
            pace_x[i] = 1
        return pace_y

    plt.plot(np.cumsum(pace_x), np.cumsum(pace_y))
    plt.show()

Brownian_motion(500)
```

It does not throw and error but I can't get it to plot

EDIT:

This is similar to what I'm expecting to see:

http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/random_walk_2d_simulation/walks_1_steps_1000_plot.png

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: None, it gives me no errors. The console is blank.

Comment: I am seeing it. I am trying...will back with something :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to prepare to do undergrad physics research next semester and I need to bring my coding skills ready for the task.

Comment: why are you doing `return pace_y`?
this means you never get to `plt.show()`

Comment: I believe the last `pace_x[i] = 1` should instead be `pace_y[i] = 1`.

Comment: have you seen the answers?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi As for plotting yes, but in the arrays I get 1 and 0 instead of 1 and -1. I'm working on fixing that. I know it has to do with my "if" statements but I have not been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: @LuisFLlano I modified the code in my answer try to see if that is what you want

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I really appreciate all the help but it is still not what it should be. I have added a link to my question showing an example of a random walk. Thank you again for the help I'm extremely grateful.

Comment: what is the algorithm? we cannot deduce the steps from the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With numpy you can create boolean slices which are more efficient. Note that this does not work with Python Lists/Tuples.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random as rng

def Brownian_motion(steps):
    """
    this is a random walk function
    define the number of steps to be taken as a integer value
    """
    #these are the random numbers
    steps_x = rng(steps)
    steps_y = rng(steps)

    pace_x = np.ones_like(steps_x)
    idx = steps_x < 0.5
    pace_x[idx] = -1

    idy = steps_y < 0.5
    pace_y = np.ones_like(steps_y)
    pace_y[idy] = -1

    plt.plot(np.cumsum(pace_x), np.cumsum(pace_y))
    # plt.axis("equal") 
    # I would also add this. This way your plot won't be
    # distorted.
    plt.show()

a = Brownian_motion(500)
```

[image: Random Walk]

Answer (score 1):

You have unnecessary `return` statements at the end of your loops, so your code never gets to the plot. Remove those and the `Brownian_motion` function should have a chance to complete execution.

Comment: I did that and yes that helped complete it, but I seem to not get negative values. I thought that would be taken care of by the "if" statements I have but it appears to not work. Could you help me with that, please?

Comment: @LuisFLlano `print` the values of `steps_x` and `pace_x` to see what they hold.

Comment: I have 1 and 0 and I need those 0 to be -1. I thought my "if" statements would do the job. How can I fix them?

Comment: @LuisFLlano The problem is on the lines like `pace_x[i] = -1`. `i` is not an array index, it's a True/False value. I think you need to append -1/1 to a new data list.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what a Brownian motion simulator/ random walk simulator is but the problem in your code is that in your function you have a `return` statement (actually 2) that makes your function stop without executing the the plot.

Commenting it seems to work and it plots something (I do not know it it is what you are expecting).

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random as rng

def Brownian_motion(steps):
    """
    this is a random walk function
    define the number of steps to be taken as a integer value
    """
    #these are the random numbers
    steps_x = rng(steps)
    steps_y = rng(steps)
    #Here I change the random numbers to 1 or -1
    pace_x = (steps_x < 0.5)
    #print(pace_x)

    x_list = list()
    y_list = list()
    for i in pace_x:
        if i == False:
            #pace_x[i] = -1
            x_list.append(-1)
        else:
            #pace_x[i] = 1
            x_list.append(1)
        #return pace_x
    print("Hello there")
    pace_y = (steps_y < 0.5)
    for i in pace_y:
        if i == False:
            #pace_y[i] = -1
            y_list.append(-1)

        else:
            #pace_x[i] = 1
            y_list.append(1)
        #return pace_y
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list)
    plt.show()

Brownian_motion(500)
```

**Piece of advice**: when something is wrong in Python try to put `print` function calls in your code to check what you are expecting is correct. For example I put the line `print("Hello there")` after the return and have seen that it was never executed (now it's commented).

Comment: Or use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `return` from your function, and cast your booleans to integers

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random as rng

def Brownian_motion(steps):
    """
    this is a random walk function
    define the number of steps to be taken as a integer value
    """
    #these are the random numbers
    steps_x = rng(steps)
    steps_y = rng(steps)

    #Here I change the random numbers to 1 or -1
    pace_x = (steps_x < 0.5)*1
    for i in pace_x:
        if i == False:
            pace_x[i] = -1
        else:
            pace_x[i] = 1
        #return pace_x

    pace_y = (steps_y < 0.5)*1
    for i in pace_y:
        if i == False:
            pace_y[i] = -1
        else:
            pace_x[i] = 1
        #return pace_y

    plt.plot(np.cumsum(pace_x), np.cumsum(pace_y))
    plt.show()

Brownian_motion(500)
```